# npm start failed to compile

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json, npm-start

Here is the issue with npm start, running react-scripts start. Please, could anyone help me with it?

I am trying to use Swiper in my app and I am getting this Error on console.

!UPDATED: added code where the swiper is used.

```
Failed to compile.
./node_modules/swiper/dist/js/swiper.esm.bundle.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '/home/lemes/Projects/idealnemoloko-react/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/assertThisInitialized' in '/home/lemes/Projects/idealnemoloko-react/node_modules/swiper/dist/js'
```

Laso providing you a package.json

I pray that would help

package.json

```
{
  "name": "idealnemoloko-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": ".",
  "dependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^2.0.1",
    "gsap": "^2.0.2",
    "react": "^16.6.0",
    "react-art": "^16.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.0",
    "react-native": "^0.57.4",
    "react-native-web": "^0.9.6",
    "react-on-images-loaded": "^2.1.9",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1",
    "swiper": "^4.4.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Files where I'm using swiper:
recipes/index.js

```
this.swiper = new Swiper('.recipes-swiper-container', {
  direction: 'vertical',
  speed: 1000,
  slidesPerView: 1,
  allowTouchMove: false,
  mousewheel: true,
  pagination: {
    el: '.recipes-swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
  },
  on: {
    transitionEnd: this.handleSlideTrans
  }
});
```

main/index.js

```
 hasLoaded() {
    if(this.state.isLoading === true) {
      this.setState({isLoading: false})

      this.swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        direction: 'vertical',
        preventInteractionOnTransition: true,
        speed: 1000,
        autoplay: {
          delay: 5000,
          disableOnInteraction: false,
        },
        slidesPerView: 1,
        initialSlide: this.props.index,
        allowTouchMove: false,
        mousewheel: {
          eventsTarged: '#main-page'
        },
        pagination: {
          el: '.swiper-pagination',
          type: 'bullets',
          clickable: true
        },
      });

      this.swiperInfo = new Swiper('.swiper-container-info', {
        direction: 'vertical',
        preventInteractionOnTransition: true,
        speed: 1000,
        slidesPerView: 1,
        allowTouchMove: false,
        initialSlide: this.props.index
      });

      this.swiper.on('slideNextTransitionStart', () => {
        this.swiperInfo.slideNext();
      });
      this.swiper.on('slidePrevTransitionStart', () => {
        this.swiperInfo.slidePrev();
      });

      var pag = document.getElementsByClassName('swiper-pagination')[0].clientHeight;
      document.getElementById('info-back').style.top = 'calc(50% - ' + pag/window.innerHeight*100/3.25 + 'vh)';
    }
  }

  swiperStart() {
    this.swiper.autoplay.start();
  }
```

why/index.js

```
this.swiper = new Swiper('.why-swiper-container', {
      direction: 'vertical',
      speed: 1000,
      slidesPerView: 1,
      allowTouchMove: false,
      mousewheel: true,
      pagination: {
        el: '.why-swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
      },
      on: {
        transitionEnd: this.handleSlideTrans
      }
    });
```

Comment: can you add the Component Code where you are using the swiper code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are requiring the `Swiper`.

You need to import the `Swiper` package like this:

`import Swiper from 'swiper/dist/js/swiper.js'`

Comment: So if I'm using `import Swiper from 'swiper';` that's not enough and I need to import it form `'swiper/dist/js/swiper.js'`?

Comment: Yeah you need to import if from the path where it is exported.
Reference: https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/issues/2335

Comment: Thank you the issue seems to be resolved, but another one has appeared: `./src/NotFound.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '/home/lemes/Projects/idealnemoloko-react/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/classCallCheck' in '/home/lemes/Projects/idealnemoloko-react/src'`

But the file is directly in src directory and I'm importing it in App.js like this: `import NotFound from './NotFound';`

Comment: The on is from babel. You need to check the version and import

Comment: I've just removed node_modules and run npm install. Everything is working from now. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Glad To Help, can you please do a upvote and accept it as answer to prize me for my effort?